How to Efficiently Handle JSON Data for Table Display and CSV/JSON Download in a Web Application?
Let's say I have a frontend where it fetches a list of JSON objects. I want to display some chosen values from this list of objects in a table.
Additionally, I need to allow users to download either the displayed table as a CSV or all the JSON objects as they prefer.
Normally, I would keep two copies of the data: one as JSON and the other as a list of lists to be converted to CSV. However, this approach seems to consume twice the memory.
Alternatively, I can store the JSON data and convert it to a table whenever needed. But this means I have to repeatedly convert the JSON when the user wants to download the CSV and at the start when I want to display the data in the table.
Do I have to choose between these two options? If so, what is the best approach? Are there any better ways to handle this situation efficiently?

the question is not clear to me. that makes it kinda hard to answer. can you elaborate on the two options you gave? it seems you get the JSON and display the table regardless, do you mean to ask if you should either generate the CSV when you create the table even if the user wont need it or generate the CSV on demand like only when the user asks for it?

I want to display the table always.  I am asking whether there is a way to show the table and download the CSV and the JSON without keeping two copies of the data.
The user may download the CSV or JSON whenever they want.

My first option was to convert the JSON into a form that is easy to convert into a CSV or display in a table and store both data structures.
The second option was to keep the JSON and map the values as needed. But since I need the table always, I think this is also similar to storing data again.

Given these assumpsions:

you have the JSON data on the frontend.
this data is dynamic, so it changes enough that you cannot reasonably pre-generate it.
the data is displayed as a table on the frontend by default.
the user might require the data as CSV.

I think it will be the most efficient in the long term to generate the CSV on demand from the JSON data. my reasoning for this is that, the user might not need the data as CSV, since its the less common presentation type, it should be deferred to be generated on demand. the most efficient work is no work.
transforming the JSON data to another format that can be used to display the table and also generate the CSV wont save any work, to the contrary, it just adds another step.
Let me know of any misgiving with my answer.
PS: efficiency considerations are important but before investing too much in optimizations make sure your situation requires the extra effort to support a larger scale of usage (if you expect to have or already have more users, larger datasets, increasing computation complexity).

Thank you for your answer. I was wondering, since table and CSV formats are somewhat similar, doesn't it make sense to store the data in some structure like a list of lists?
I agree with your last note, but just wanted to know whether there are better options.

i get it, as for my take on this, if you could use a more optimized data structure than JSON that would serve both goals better, then maybe you could just respond with it from the server instead of the JSON? after all, the server doesnt have to respond in JSON. but you should prove it really will be more efficient if there is a cost of increased complexity
